# How to keep vue reactivity when getting a string from another reactive object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I know that the title maybe a bit complex to understand (I didn't know how to put it simply), so here's a minimal example. Imagine I got a reactive object ObjectA and I try to copy one if its property:

```js
const objectA = reactive({
    name: "test"
})

const objectB_01 = reactive({
    name: a.name
}) // lose reactivity

const objectB_02 = reactive({
    name: ref(a.name)
}) // lose reactivity

const objectB_03 = reactive({
    get name() { return a.name }
}) // keep reactivity
```

When I have a template that look like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ objectA.name }}</div>
</template>
```

Then, the name is reactive (meaning, if I change it somewhere, the template gets updated instantly).

But it does not work `objectB_01.name`, nor `objectB_02.name`. It only works with `objectB_03.name`, but If find it a bit of a hacky solution.

My question is: **is there a proper way of doing that?** I mean, using a get operator does works but is really not that clean, I find...

Comment: I think you can simply use `Object.assign()` method to maintain the reactivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value to be reactive across both objectA and objectB, you need a single source of the value, so getters and setters are the only way.

```js
const objectB_03 = reactive({
    get name() { return a.name },
    set name(value) { a.name = value }
}) // keep reactivity
```

In fact, Vue2 data does just that, ref [How Changes Are Tracked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked)

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data option, Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them to **getter/setters**

Comment: Hum, that's probably how vue3 is working too. After some digging, I found that I could use getOwnPropertyDescriptor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to retrieve the getter, but it's too verbose for me... I'll stick to using directly getter (and setter if needed).

Answer (score 2):

For example reactive api

`reactive` will unwrap all the deep **refs**, while maintaining the ref reactivity

```
const count = ref(1)
const obj = reactive({ count })

// ref will be unwrapped
console.log(obj.count === count.value) // true

// it will update `obj.count`
count.value++
console.log(count.value) // 2
console.log(obj.count) // 2

// it will also update `count` ref
obj.count++
console.log(obj.count) // 3
console.log(count.value) // 3
```

You should look at more this; https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive